# Extracting json fields using XSLT

Tags: json, xml, xslt, ibm-datapower

I am new to XSLT, currently I have a json string and I need to derive particular field from the json string . I am currently using fn:parse-json with map:get but the resultant seems to be empty .

Below is the sample snippet:

```
<xsl:variable name="json-temp" select="fn:parse-json($json-str)" />

<xsl:variable name="result" select="map:get($json-temp,2)" />
```

When I try to print result (Or) json-temp both seems to be empty - Can someone please help here. and let me know if I am missing anything.

json-str variable has the following value:

```
{
"testName":"pppp",
"testID":"1234p",
"testDept":"Dept"
}
```

Comment: You've tagged this ibm-datapower, but you are using functions that are only available in XSLT 3.0. Are you sure that your XSLT processor supports parse-json() and map:get()?

Comment: Hi Michael.. Thanks a lot for your reply... I am using API Connect 5.087(I am totally new to this too) ...have you come across a similiar problem statement in IBM API Connect ... if so can you please suggest the best approach to be tried out

Comment: I don't know API Connect, but if it implemented XSLT 3.0 then I would almost certainly know about it. Your options are to switch to an XSLT 3.0 processor (which in practice means Saxon) or to call out to external functions that might be available in your environment (but I can't help you with that).

Comment: Thanks Michael - I just got to know on the info that API Connect version being used supports XSLT 2 ...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `map:get($json-temp, 'testID')` (in XPath 3) or `$json-temp?testID` in XPath 3.1. I am not sure which value you want to extract with `map:get($json-temp,2)` as the map has no key of the value `2`, that call would only make sense for e.g. `map { 2: 'foo' }` to extract e.g. `foo`.

Comment: Hi Martin,Thanks a lot for your comment - I tried with map:get($json-temp, 'testID'), but the same was empty too ... infact I tried printing $json-temp and it was empty..not sure if I am missing anything syntatically... To add on I am using XSLT inside IBM API Connect

Comment: I think my suggestion works with XSLT and XPath 3, not sure whether DataPower supports that.

Comment: Yes you may be correct - Is there a way to do in older versions of XSLT which you know of ... Can you please suggest

Comment: Hi Martin - Can you please help with an approach in XSLT 2

Comment: @PavithranRajendran, sorry, XSLT 2 has no support or no standardized support for JSON, I am not familiar with any DataPower specific stuff, if it supports `parse-json` then I would expect it to support the approaches I have shown, but if there is no support for `parse-json` then I have no idea what to use instead as I don't know details about DataPower.

Comment: No prob Martin...ur help is much appreciated...I found an alternate solution by passing the variable to gatewayscript and I was able to retrieve the value using js....Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use JSON in DataPower is by using GatewayScript instead of XSLT. If you really need to stick to XSLT, you can try using:

```
<xsl:variable name="jsonx" select="dp:stringToJSONx($json-str)"/>
```

From there, you can extract the field you want by using XPath on the resulting JSONx document.